# Azure VM: How to send Start/Stopped/Restart Events to Webapp

Tags: python, azure, events, triggers, virtual-machine

I have a Webapp that writes the status of Azure VMs in a DB. I want to be able to have the DB update automatically every time a VM is started/stopped/restarted. How do I set up a trigger that POST to my Webapp when the VM is started/stopped/restarted?   I'm using the Azure Python SDK.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write code to achieve this you could use EventGrids in Azure linked to a logic app which would write straight into your database. Here is an example of how to set up an [EventGrid to send emails when linked to a logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app). T[his is an example in how to connect a Logic App to a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure). The combination of these two examples will allow you to use Azure native technologies to achieve your goal.

Alternatively instead of writing straight to the database you could use the logic app to POST to your website using one of the connectors.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for opening me up to this service. I took a look briefly and it seemed overkill for what I"m trying to do.  This led me to looking into "Alerts" and "Action Group", which does exactly what I need. 

I set up an Alert for VM startup/shutdown and attach it to a webhook which POST to a URL. Very neat.